# Print header row and each row in file the file, side by side in columns

Tags: perl

Hi I have a tsv file that i am trying to print the header row and each line of the file side by side ie in columns.
 Unfortunatley i am bit confused on how to join the lines in a print statement.

```cpp
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
local $" = "'\n'";      
my @temp;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = join "\t", $_;
    push @temp, @columns;
}

my $Header_row = shift (@temp);
my @head;
my $abc;
my @abc = split(/\t/,$Header_row);
        for my $abc(@abc) {
        push @head, $abc ."\n";


}
my @roows;
my $elements;
        foreach (@temp){
        chomp;
my $line = $_;
my @elements = split ("\t", $line);
        for  $elements(@elements){
        push @roows, $elements ."\n";

}
}
        #print @head, $abc ."\n";
        #print @roows, $elements ."\n";



__DATA__
Year    Tonn    Class   Cargo   Type
88  61  T   Rice    Truck
89  55  G   Corn    Train   
92  93  S   Peas    Ship
```

## required Output

**OUTPUT**

```
Year    88
Tonn    61  
Class   T   
Cargo   Rice    
Type    Truck

Year    89
Tonn    55  
Class   G   
Cargo   Corn    
Type    Train

Year    92
Tonn    93  
Class   S   
Cargo   Peas    
Type    Ship
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. It looks like you're just trying to read the contents in and print the out again, and I don't see why you're modifying them at all. An example of your expected output would help

Answer (score 2):

Based on your source, this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#read the header line into @header;     
my $header_line = <DATA>;
chomp $header_line;
chomp ( my @header = split ( ' ', $header_line ); 

#iteraate data fh    
while ( <DATA> ) {
    #strip linefeed 
    chomp;
    #read this row into a hash 
    my %row; @row{@header} = split;
    #print this hash in the same order as the header.  
    #note - $_ is set to each element of header in turn when doing this. 
    print "$_\t$row{$_}\n" for @header;
    #insert extra linefeed
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
Year    Tonn    Class   Cargo   Type
88  61  T   Rice    Truck
89  55  G   Corn    Train
92  93  S   Peas    Ship
```

Note - you can condense further that 'read headers' to:

```
chomp ( my @header = split ( ' ', <DATA> ) );
```

Which does the same thing, but might be a bit harder to follow.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to read all the lines into `@temp` before looping through to print them out. It would be more efficient to read just the first line to get the headings and then loop through the remaining lines printing them immediately:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @temp;

my $line = <DATA>;
chomp($line);
my @head = split "\t", $line;

foreach $line (<DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @elements = split ("\t", $line);
    foreach my $i (0..$#head) {
        print $head[$i], "\t", $elements[$i], "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
Year    Tonn    Class   Cargo   Type
88  61  T   Rice    Truck
89  55  G   Corn    Train
92  93  S   Peas    Ship
```

The `print` line could also be written as:

```
print "$head[$i]\t$elements[$i]\n";
```

I just thought it was a little clearer to separate out all the parts.